# Website connection is not secure depending on device

Tags: android, ssl, web, https, ssl-certificate

When I visit https://matchflix.ch on a PC or Android 8 phone, the connection is secure:

[image]

However, when visiting from an Android 12 Samsung phone, it says that the connection is NOT secure. I just don't understand how this can be?

[image]
[image]

PS: The site is currently not yet live and therefore needs a username to access which is "demo".

Comment: Whichever Web browser you are using on that phone does not like your SSL certificate. Your root certificate seems to be Let's Encrypt's (ISRG Root X1); perhaps Samsung does not trust that as a root.

Comment: "I just don't understand how this can be?" Because there is a ton of parameters that go into a TLS handshake, and all need to be aligned for a successful connection. You can test your server on Qualys SSLabs website or other similar one to see its settings and even which clients will connect successfully to it or not. If all green there, then it is a problem locally on your device. But in any cases your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: Thank you, @PatrickMevzek. I know, it does not really belong here, but where should I post it? On https://serverfault.com/?

Comment: [su] most probably, [sf] is for server administration in a business setting, so that would be a good place only if you are the administrator of the website you mention and you have a specific question on TLS configuration. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=matchflix.ch clearly shows the configuration is ok and the handshake simulation section shows it should work with almost all smartphones on the market today. If your smartphone has a specific problem then it might be specific to your smartphone/its configuration and/or the network you are in. Did you try others?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks! Can I move this question myself to *Super User*? Well, it works on my phone, but I have Android 8. And with all the new phones in the shop (iPhone, Samsung) it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that HTTP had no force redirect to HTTPS. So, some browser/phones used HTTP, others HTTPS when typing in the pure domain in the browser.